# Problem with upgrading because an unmigrated module

Tags: migrations, 9

I am trying to migrate a Drupal 8 site to Drupal 9. Though most of the migrations have gone easily, this site breaks because it uses the Video module, which hasn't been updated for Drupal 9.
Specifically, the problem happens when I try to run `drush updb`. I geet this error message.

> Unable to determine class for field type 'video' found in the 'field.storag  e.paragraph.field_video_item' configuration

What would the steps needed to by-pass the problem be?

The module seems quite abandoned; I don't keep my breath waiting Drupal 9 version to be created.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about the [Video module](https://www.drupal.org/project/video).

For any module that does not have a Drupal 9 release, you basically have three options, in order of difficulty (easy to hard):

1. Find patches/a fork of the module (usually in [the issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/video?categories=All)) that supports Drupal 9.
2. Update the module to be compatible with Drupal 9 yourself.
3. Find a replacement module that is compatible with Drupal 9 and migrate your data to that, then uninstall the incompatible module.

For #1, looking through the issue queue, there are a few patches you could try:

- https://www.drupal.org/project/video/issues/3137499
- https://www.drupal.org/project/video/issues/3174989
- https://www.drupal.org/project/video/issues/3101969

For #3, Drupal now has excellent Media support in core, so if possible, I would try to migrate your video data to core media, as that would guarantee you an easy upgrade path to Drupal 10 and beyond.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got over the problem by just marking the video module Drupal 9 compatible. It probably isn't very good/healthy a solution but got me over the obstacle and I can try to implement now the similar functionality with Media core support.

As I haven't worked earlier with the site I have to find out how heavily the video module is used in the site but at least so far hasn't hit my head into a stone.

If someone comes here but doesn't know how to mark the module Drupal 9 compatible it's by adding the following line to the video.info.yml

```
core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9
```

Of course, that doesn't actually mean that the module *works*, only that Drupal thinks it has found a compatible version of the module and can go on updating the database.

Thanks Patrick for the pointer

hank